# How to combine multiple query's into one?

Tags: php, mysql, rgraph

I am running a line graph on RGraph framework, and I am using a SELECT COUNT statement for rejected, accepted, approved etc.....counting how many items was rejected or accepted etc and then dumping the query data into an array, However I am looking for an easier way to implement this query, instead of running a query on each unique row value, also thinking in the way if I have to encounter other column data besides rejected, accepted  or etc....I wouldnt, my code doesnt seem very scalable then. Please help

So far, I am running a query for each keyword, hope my code explains this.

The final variable is what i am feeding to RGRAPH, This works fine as it is, however it isn't the right way, and not very scalable, should my row data change.

```
 <?php  



    $cxn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "csvimport");

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE conclusion = 'rejected'";

    $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));

    $display = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $rejected = $display[0];

    //echo $rejected;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE conclusion = 
              'accepted'";

    $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));

    $display = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $accepted = $display[0];

    //echo $accepted;


    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE conclusion = '-'";

    $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));

    $display = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $dash = $display[0];

    //echo $dash;


    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1 WHERE conclusion = 
     'approved'";

    $result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));

    $display = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $approved = $display[0];

    //echo $approved;



    $datarray = [$rejected, $accepted, $dash, $approved];

    print_r($datarray);
    $data_string = "[" . join(", ", $datarray) . "]";
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($data_string);

?>
```

Comment: `... WHERE conclusion IN(...)` might help

Comment: Simply union all three Select then you will have 3 rows with the correct count

Comment: Dont union. Group by. Union Is for cases where individual selects work over differrent tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use GROUP BY and add the conclusion column to the result set, so

```
SELECT conclusion, COUNT(*) as total
    FROM table_1 
    WHERE conclusion in ('rejected', 'accepted', '-', 'approved')
    GROUP BY conclusion
```

Then retrieve each row of the result set

```
$totals = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {
    $totals [$row[0]] = [$row[1]];
}
```

and `$totals` will be an array something like

```
array( 'accepted' => 12, 
       'approved' => 20...)
```

If you want all of the conclusions, then just remove the `WHERE conclusion in` line and it will return all of the possibilities along with the count.

Comment: I would just add that the result Will not contain conclusions that have zero occurences.